# NullPointerException when trying to write object instance to ObjectOutputStream

Tags: java, pointers, serialization, stream, nullpointerexception

I'm getting

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:201)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:99)
    at lib.Entry.serialize(Entry.java:17)
    at main.Main.main(Main.java:8)
```

Where `Entry.java:17` is `stream.writeObject(this);` (see below)

Entry.java

```
package lib;
import java.io.*;

public class Entry { // Superclass.

    String filename; // Set below.
    String name; // Set by the subclass.

    public void main() {
        this.filename = this.name + ".ser";
        serialize();
    }

    public void serialize() {           
        try {
            FileOutputStream file = new FileOutputStream(this.filename);
            ObjectOutputStream stream = new ObjectOutputStream(file);
            stream.writeObject(this);
            stream.close();
            file.close();
            System.out.println("Serialized.");
        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Place.java

```
package lib;

public class Place extends lib.Entry { // A subclass.

    public String name;

    public Place(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

Main.java

```
package main;
import lib.Place;

public abstract class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Place room = new Place("room");
        room.serialize();
    }

}
```

Why am I getting a `NullPointerException` when using `this`? I'm trying to write the current object instance to the `ObjectOutputStream`. I'm new to Java and I have no idea how to proceed. In Python I'd use something like `stream.writeObject(self)` so by the same line of thought I used `this` in Java. I tried using `stream.writeObject(Object this);`, but it didn't work. I also tried

```
Object p = this;
stream.writeObject(p);
```

Which I guess is the same thing. It also didn't work. The idea is to have more classes (other than `Place`) extending `Entry`, allowing them to be serialized using the `Entry.serialize()` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> String name; // Set by the subclass.
> ```

That's the problem. Since you have re-defined the `name` field in subclass, it will no longer set the field in the super class using `this.name`. The `name` field in `Place` class shadows the field declared in `Entry` class.

Remove the declaration of `name` from `Place` class.

Then replace the `main()` method in `Entry` class with a parameterized constructor. I don't know why you had it in the first place. You aren't even calling it.

```
public Entry(String name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.filename = this.name + ".ser";

    // Don't call it here. Your object hasn't been fully constructed yet.
    // serialize();  
}
```

then call the super class constructor from `Place` constructor, instead of setting the field directly:

```
public Place(String name) {
    super(name);
}
```

And finally, make your `Place` class to implement `Serializable` interface. Remember, you are serializing it's instance.

Comment: I want to use the name defined in `Place`, that was not the issue. I used `Entry()` instead of `main()`, as suggested by Ravi, and maintained `String name; // Set by the subclass` and it worked. But, as you pointed out, there is no reason to have both fields, it's better to have `Entry(String name)`. And I did forgot to implement the Serializeble interface. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Generally speaking, if you want this sort of behavior, it's better to use a method than to rely on the subclasser to remember to fill in the field. Instead of `String name`, use `abstract String getName()`.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Entry#main()` isn't getting called because `Main#main()` is your `main()` method now. You need to add a constructor that initializes the *filename* in your `Entry` class as

```
   public Entry() {
        this.filename = this.name + ".ser";
    }
```