# java inheritance Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, inheritance

I am new in Java. I got a question in inheritance.
I tried to write some kinds of sorting class. They got same data structure and same methods too.
So I tried to use inheritance.
I wrote this base class.

```
public class Sort {
private int[] lst;

public Sort(int[] lst) {
    this.lst = lst;
}

public void sort() {
    return;
}

public String toString() {
    String aa = "";
    for (int innt : this.lst) {
        aa = aa + innt + "" + " ";
    }
    return aa;
}
}
```

and this

```
public class Select extends Sort{
private int[] lst;

public Select(int[] lst) {
    super(lst);
}

public void sort() {
    for (int i = 0; i < this.lst.length; i++) {
        int small = lst[i];
        int small_ind = i;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < this.lst.length; j++) {
            if (lst[j] < small) {
                small = lst[j];
                small_ind = j;
            }
        }
        int temp = lst[i];
        lst[i] = small;
        lst[small_ind] = temp;
    }
}
}
```

but when I run this

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] a = {5, 6, 7, 5, 7, 3, 2, 1, 4, 8};
    Sort sl = new Select(a);
    sl.sort();
    System.out.println(sl.toString());
}
}
```

It does not work. Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
It only work when I move the toString method to Select class, and remove "extends Sort".
Would you mind helping me? Thanks.

Comment: please add whole stacktrace.

Comment: possible duplicate of [NullPointerException when trying to write object instance to ObjectOutputStream](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18138526/nullpointerexception-when-trying-to-write-object-instance-to-objectoutputstream)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: I don't understand why there are close votes. Seems like a valid question to me.

Comment: @Ross Drew Maybe some people are after a certain badge.

Comment: oh is there a badge for it, one sees

Comment: @Jens Hi, these are all the code in my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you have different lists! In any implementation one. Every one of them are private for his own instance.

This should work:

```
public abstract class Sort {
protected int[] lst;

public Sort(int[] lst) {
    this.lst = lst;
}

public abstract void sort();

public String toString() {
    String aa = "";
    for (int innt : this.lst) {
        aa = aa + innt + "" + " ";
    }
    return aa;
}
}
```

Now the list is protected and accessable in any implemtation. Also the class is abstract to prevend direct use, you have to make an implementation now. Also the sort method is abstract to make sure that the implementation is implementing it ;)

And here the implementation:

```
public class Select extends Sort{

public Select(int[] lst) {
    super(lst);
}


public void sort() {
    for (int i = 0; i < this.lst.length; i++) {
        int small = lst[i];
        int small_ind = i;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < this.lst.length; j++) {
            if (lst[j] < small) {
                small = lst[j];
                small_ind = j;
            }
        }
        int temp = lst[i];
        lst[i] = small;
        lst[small_ind] = temp;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: This wont work unless the child class also removes it's definition of `lst`

Comment: sure! because it already exist protected in your abstract base class. Inherhitance basics ;)

Answer (score 2):

It shouldn't work if you move `toString()` because it looks like the `NullPointerException` is happening when you call `sort()` not `toString()` because in the line:-

```
for (int i = 0; i < this.lst.length; i++) {
```

the `lst` you are trying to access a member (`length`) of hasn't been created, only the parents private version of it.

You either need to get rid of the child class' `lst` and make the parents version `protected` not `private`:-

```
protected int[] lst; //In Sort class
```

or set the childs `lst` in it's constructor:-

```
public Select(int[] lst) { //In Select class
    this.lst = lst;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have tested your code. I have changed small things in your code and it runs properly. I don't know whether this will help or not.

It works for me. You can try it.

The whole code is ,

In Sort class,

```
package testing;

public class Sort {
    private int[] lst;

    public Sort(int[] lst) {
        this.lst = lst;
    }

    public void sort(int[] a) {
        return;
    }

    public String toString() {
        String aa = "";
        for (int innt : this.lst) {
            aa = aa + innt + "" + " ";
        }
        return aa;
    }
}
```

In Select class,

```
package testing;

public class Select extends Sort{
    private int[] lst;

    public Select(int[] lst) {
        super(lst);
    }

    public void sort(int[] lst) {


       for (int i = 0; i <lst.length; i++) {
            int small = lst[i];

            int small_ind = i;

            for (int j = i + 1; j <lst.length; j++) {

                if (lst[j] < small) {
                    small = lst[j];
                    small_ind = j;
                }
            }
            int temp = lst[i];
            lst[i] = small;
            lst[small_ind] = temp;
        }

    }
}
```

and in Test Class,

```
package testing;

public class Test{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int[] a = {5, 6, 7, 5, 7, 3, 2, 1, 4, 8};
        Sort sl = new Select(a);
        sl.sort(a);
        //sl.sort();
        System.out.println(sl.toString());
    }

}
```